# Android: Adding contacts with country codes

Tags: android

How can I add a phone number to the android phone book including the respective country code.

Code I Have

```
private void addContact(Context context,String phone){

    String DisplayName = "Programmer";
    String MobileNumber = phone;
    String emailID = "coder@gmail.com";
    String company = "Programmers Inc";
    String jobTitle = "Duhhh";

    ArrayList <ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList < ContentProviderOperation > ();

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(
            ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
            .build());

    //------------------------------------------------------ Names
    if (DisplayName != null) {
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(
                ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME,
                        DisplayName).build());
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------ Mobile Number
    if (MobileNumber != null) {
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.
                newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, MobileNumber)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
                .build());
    }


    //------------------------------------------------------ Email
    if (emailID != null) {
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA, emailID)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_WORK)
                .build());
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------ Organization
    if (!company.equals("") && !jobTitle.equals("")) {
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.COMPANY, company)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE_WORK)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TITLE, jobTitle)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE_WORK)
                .build());
    }

    // Asking the Contact provider to create a new contact
    try {
        context.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately when run

```
addContact(this,"+27622730XXX"); // +27 is country code, 0622730XXX is my cell number
```

In my phone book the contact has been saved with phone number **+2727622730XXX** with duplication of the country code.

**Question**

How can i make sure that the phone does not try to guess the country code and avoid this duplication.

Comment: I feel phone might not guess the country code. There must be something wrong somewhere else. Because U can store a phone number without country code as well

Answer (score -1):

If you can obtain the phone number in +272xxxxxxx format, you can force this number to be recognized by setting NORMALIZED_NUMBER in addition to NUMBER value.

As per Android documentation, NORMALIZED_NUMBER should be the E164 representation of the number. If it is not set, the system tries to guess it automatically.

Comment: You are telling him that he can, but not how ? A simple code snippet would probably go a long way.